# Run configure hook of "mysql-workbench-community" snap if present (run hook "configure": cannot locate base snap core22: No such file or directory)

Tags: 22.04, mysql, mysql-workbench

```
Run configure hook of "mysql-workbench-community" snap if present (run hook "configure": cannot locate base snap core22: No such file or directory)
```

I have configured mysql server  on ubuntu 22.04 but when i try to install mysql workbench i am getting this issue.

```
sudo snap install core ->Already Installed
sudo snap refresh core -> All snaps up to date
```

I don't know how can I get rid of this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot repair the broken snap core22 on Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1456802/cannot-repair-the-broken-snap-core22-on-ubuntu-22-04)

Answer (score 0):

Most suggestions for this issue involve upgrading the core snap to beta or edge and then downgrading back to stable. I suppose this essentially reinstalls it.
Anyway, run this:
`sudo snap refresh core22 --beta`

Then run this:
`sudo snap refresh core22 --stable`

Then try re-installing MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Finally, I got it it is not connecting to the database because of auth_socket.Here how is solved this issue:sudo mysql -u root -p
SELECT User,Host,plugin FROM mysql.user;
USE mysql;
UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE user='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit
service mysql restart