Ubuntu 22.04 snapd seems to be preventing applications from starting
I was repeatedly having prompts to update Brave Browser, despite following the prompt and updating the browser, and I saw that it was from the "snap store", so I uninstalled and reinstalled snapd.I uninstalled and reinstalled Brave Browser, but now the Brave Browser would try to start, but wouldn't start.
I try to start Brave Browser from the CLI, and this is what happens:
el_gallo_azul@desktop-ubuntu:~$ brave
Command 'brave' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo snap install brave

el_gallo_azul@desktop-ubuntu:~S sudo snap tnstall brave
[sudo] password for el_gallo_azul:
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
Run configure hook of "brave" snap if present (run hook "configure": cannot locate base snap core22: No such file or directory)

el_gallo_azul@desktop-ubuntu:~$ standard-notes
cannot locate base snap core22: No such file or directory

el_gallo_azul@desktop-ubuntu:~$ sudo snap install core22
snap "core22" is already installed, see 'snap help refresh'

I just ran through the same thing with Mozilla Firefox browser, in an attempt to paste the CLI text into this AskUbuntu question, but it wouldn't start. A similar problem occurred when I tried to start it from the CLI, and again when I tried to install it (although it was already installed).
I then tried to use the Standard Notes app as a place to store this CLI text, so I could transfer it across OSs and paste it into AskUbuntu, but the Standard Notes application wouldn't start, either.
I just tried again, and there was something about core22 missing, which I then installed, but it did not make any difference.
I am not able to use Ubuntu 22.04. I am only able to use Tails 6.4 for now.
Edit 20240630: As requested, I add the following.
I haven't been able to use Ubuntu for a few weeks now, so when I booted into it, the first thing I did was a big, fat update, which included kernel image and a load of 'snap' updates. I mistakenly got my hopes up. Then I did the following.
$ brave
Command brave' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo snap install brave
$ sudo snap install brave
[sudo] password for el_gallo_azul:
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
Run configure hook of "brave" snap if present (run hook "configure": cannot locate base snap core22: No such file or directory)
$ sudo snap refresh
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
Run post-refresh hook of "firefox" snap if present (run hook "post-refresh": cannot locate base snap core22: No such file or directory)

Edit 20240704 I add the following after following more suggestions in the comments. I hope I have corrected all the OCR errors.
el_gallo_azul@desktop-ubuntu:~$ sudo snap remove firefox
[sudo] password for el_gallo_azul:
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
Remove data for snap "firefox" (4424) (unlinkat /var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/en_AU.aff: read-only file systen)
el_gallo_azul@desktop-ubuntu:~$ 

el_gallo_azul@desktop-ubuntu:~$ brave
Command 'brave' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo snap install brave
el_gallo_azul@desktop-ubuntu:~$ sudo snap install brave
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
Run configure hook of "brave" snap if present (run hook "configure": cannot locate base snap core22: No such file
el_gallo_azul@desktop-ubuntu:~$ sudo snap refresh brave
error: snap "brave" is not installed
el_gallo_azul@desktop-ubuntu:~$

el_gallo_azul@desktop-ubuntu:-$ sudo snap refresh brave
error: snap "brave" is not installed
el_gallo_azul@desktop-ubuntu:~$ apt policy snapd
snapd:
Installed: 2.63+22.04
Candidate: 2.63+22.04
Version table:
*** 2.63+22.04 500
500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
2.58+22.04.1 500
500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main and64 Packages
2.55.3+22.04 500
500 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
el_gallo_azul@desktop-ubuntu:~$

el_gallo_azul@desktop-ubuntu:~$ cd ~/snap
el_gallo_azul@desktop-ubuntu:~/snap$ ls
canonical-livepatch drawing firefox snapd-desktop-integration snap-store standard-notes
el_gallo_azul@desktop-ubuntu:~$

el_gallo_azul@desktop-ubuntu:~/snap$ sudo apt purge snapd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following package was autonatically installed and ts no longer required:
libopenshot25
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
snapd*
0 to upgrade, 0 O newly install, 1 to remove and 6 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 104 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 218837 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing snapd (2.63+22.04)
stopping snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service
stopping unit snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service
Maiting until unit snap.canontcal-livepatch.canontcal-livepatchd.service ls stopped [attenpt 1]
snap.canonical-livepatch.canontcal-livepatchd.service is stopped
Harning: Stopping snapd.service, but it can still be activated by:
snapd.socket
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1)
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.20-2ubuntu4.1) ...
Processing triggers for matlcap (3.70+nmulubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
(Reading database ... 218747 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for snapd (2.63+22.04)
Stopping snap.canontcal-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service
"..
Stopping unit snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service
Hatting until untt snap.canontcal-livepatch.canontcal-Ltvepatchd.service is stopped [attenpt 1]
snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service is stopped
Removing snap.canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.service
Stopping snap-bare-5.mount
Stopping unit snap-bare-5.mount
Waiting until unit snap-bare-5.nount is stopped [attempt 1]
snap-bare-5.mount ts stopped
Removing snap bare and revision 5
Removing snap-bare-5.mount
Stopping snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-282.mount
Stopping unit snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-282.mount
Hatting until untt snap-canontcal\x2dltvepatch-282.mount ts stopped [attenpt 1]
snap-canonical|x2dlivepatch-282.mount is stopped.
Removing snap canontcal-livepatch and reviston 282
Removing snap-canonical\x2dlivepatch-282.mount
Stopping snap-core18- 2823.mount
Stopping untt snap-core18-2823 Mount
Waiting untll unit snap-core18-2823.mount ts stopped [attempt 1]
snap-core18-2823.mount is stopped.
Removing snap core18 and reviston 2823
Removing snap-core18-2823.mount
Stopping snap- core18-2829.
Mount
Stopping untt snap-core18-2829.mount
Hatting untll untt snap-core18-2829.mount ls stopped [attenpt 1]
Snap- Core18-2829. .nount ts stopped.
Removing SOAD core1R and revision 7879
(remove overlap)
snap-core18-2829.mount is stopped
Removing snap core18 and revision 2829
Removing snap-core18-2829.mount
Stopping snap-core20-2318.mount
Stopping untt snap-core20-2318.mount
Waiting until untt snap-core20-2318.mount is stopped [attempt 1]
snap-core20-2318.mount is stopped.
Removing snap core20 and revision 2318
Removing snap-core20-2318.mount
Stopping snap-core22-1380.mount
Stopping unit snap-core22-1380.mount
Waiting until unit snap-core22-1380.mount is stopped [attempt 1]
Removing snap core22 and revision 1380
Removing snap-core22-1380.mount
Stopping snap-firefox-4424.mount
Stopping unit snap-firefox-4424.mount
Waiting until unit snap-firefox-4424.mount is stopped [attempt 1]
snap-firefox-4424.mount is stopped.
Removing snap firefox and revision 4424
rm: cannot remove '/var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/en_AU.aff': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/en_AU.dic': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/en_US.aff': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/var/snap/firefox/common/host-hunspell/en_US.dic': Read-only file systen
dpkg: error processing package snapd (--purge):
installed snapd package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
snapd
E: Sub-process /usr/btn/dpkg returned_an error code (1)
el_gallo_azul@desktop-ubuntu:~$

el_gallo_azul@desktop-ubuntu:~$ sudo snap refresh
[sudo] password for el_gallo_azul:
All snaps up to date.
el_gallo_azul@desktop-ubuntu:-$

And lastly, snap list.I was not able to extract the text in columns, so I attach the corresponding image:


There is no Ubuntu 22.03. Please edit and correct version info.

"something about" is too vague to offer useful advice. Please edit the question to accurately show the complete, actual error message(s).

I know. That's why I'd prefer to copy the CLI text and paste here. However, it is not possible to paste the text into any application in Ubuntu and access it here in Tails.. If I get a chance, I'll take a photo, and then transcribe the text here.

I've just got back from the hospital Emergency Department, got my internet working again after it had stopped working last night, and may get a chance to take that photo in Ubuntu later today.

Please use [code block]s to format command output as a whole, not online code formatting on individual lines, as your post has already been edited once before to that end

Thanks. I'm not impatient, but I won't get a chance to try your suggestions today. I may have a chance tomorrow.

I've done each of those steps, got photos of the terminal, used OCR to convert to text, and will attempt to edit the question now.

@el_gallo_azul Most of the apps in the snaps are having issues. Try to install Brave Browser using the steps mentioned in their official website. After installing, you can launch it through terminal using brave-browser command.

this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1456802/cannot-repair-the-broken-snap-core22-on-ubuntu-22-04 could help you

Hm. I don't have /var/snap/core22 in my Ubuntu 22.04. I do have /snap/core22. I would like to check that this still works.

As suggested by @Lety, the answer is at https://askubuntu.com/a/1458661/91583

https://askubuntu.com/a/1458661/91583
This was what worked for me, as suggested by @Lety, who deserves the bounty.
